# Using identifier in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has insert, update, and delete functionality.  On my update statement, I'm not sure how to set my identifier `PersonID` = to the currently selected identifier in the gridview that is being updated.  Is there a common method that people use to achieve this functionality?

Code for Asp.net GRIDVIEW

```
<div id="dvGrid" style="padding: 0px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="blue" HeaderStyle-BackColor="aqua"
                    ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="EditCustomer" OnRowUpdating="UpdateCustomer"
                    OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" Height="95px">
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server"  Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" width="60px"  MaxLength="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Last Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" width="60px" MaxLength="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Age">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" Width="30px" MaxLength="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Activity Card">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblActivityCard" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityCard")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivityCard" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityCard")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivityCard" Width="50px" MaxLength="7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Cell Phone">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCell" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cell#")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCell" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cell#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCell" Width="70px" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Emergency Phone">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEmergency" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Emergency#")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmergency" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Emergency#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmergency" width="70px" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>               
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Boat Type">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblBoat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CraftType")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CraftType")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoat" Width="80px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Initials">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblInitials" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Initials")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInitials" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Initials")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInitials" width="30px" MaxLength="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Group #">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group#")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroup" MaxLength="2" Width="20px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PersonID")%>'
                                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" Text="Delete"
                                    OnClick="DeleteCustomer"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </itemtemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="AddNewCustomer" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    </Columns>
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Aqua" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </div>
```

Method for Update:

```
protected void UpdateCustomer(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string nFirstName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
    string nLastName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
    string nEmergency = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmergency")).Text;
    string nCell = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCell")).Text;
    string nAge = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtAge")).Text;
    string nActivityCard = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtActivityCard")).Text;
    string nBoat = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBoat")).Text;
    string nInitials = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtInitials")).Text;
    string nGroup = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtGroup")).Text;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "update Person set FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, " +
     "Emergency#=@Emergency, Cell#=@Cell, Age=@Age, ActivityCard=@ActivityCard, Initials=@Initials, CraftType=@Boat, Group#=@Group " +
     "where Person.PersonID=Person.PersonID;" +
     "SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName AS FirstName, Person.LastName AS LastName, Person.Emergency# AS Emergency#, Person.Cell# AS Cell#, Person.Age AS Age, " +
    "Person.ActivityCard AS ActivityCard, Person.CraftType AS CraftType, Person.Initials AS Initials, Person.Group# AS Group# " +
    "FROM Person INNER JOIN " +
    "TripSchedule ON Person.PersonID = TripSchedule.PersonID where TripSchedule.Date = @Date and " +
    "TripSchedule.Time = @Time and TripSchedule.TripType = @Type order by Person.Group#;";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nFirstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nLastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emergency", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nEmergency;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cell", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nCell;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nAge;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityCard", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nActivityCard;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Initials", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nInitials;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Boat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nBoat;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nGroup;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", ddlTripTime.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ddlTripType.SelectedItem.ToString());

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for gridview definition and your `update` function?

Comment: Are you using `asp:SqlDataSource` with `UpdateCommand`?

Comment: Ok thanks, looking. Where you need the value for the `PersonID`? Do you have the `PersonID` in the datasource you're binding to the gridview?

Comment: @DennisR As you can see in my SQL statement, it's currently set to `Where Person.PersonID=Person.PersonID` and when I update one record, they all duplicate that record.  SO when I choose to update a record in the gridview, I would like only THAT record to be updated.

Comment: Ok, got it. Is `PersonID` int or string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First specify `DataKeyNames="PersonID"` for your gridview definition.

Here is how you get the `PersonID` value in your `UpdateCustomer` function in code behind.

```
protected void UpdateCustomer(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   // assuming that the value of your PersonID is numeric value
   long personID = long.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["PersonID"].ToString());

   ....

}
```

The `personID` value you can pass as an argument to your `WHERE` clause.

Alternatively you can declare a HiddenField in your gridview and bind `PersonID` which you can access in you `UpdateCustomer` function using `FindControl` method.